# Rewriting old sites urls to new site's urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The old site's urls are like:
example.com/dsk/newslong.php?id=5206

New site's urls are like:
example.com/dsk/?p=5206

The .htaccess below is not working in any way.
And more, i have 5K posts to map, and would like to have it working like a macro:

(every number after http://www.example.com/dsk/newslong.php?id=XXX should be rewrited to /dsk/?p=XXX)

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/dsk/newslong.php?id=5206(.*)$ http://www.example.biz/dsk/?p=5206$1 [r=301,nc]
```

The server once installed newsite is returning a 404 not found on newslong.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dsk/newslong.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(id=[0-9]+)$
RewriteRule .* /dsk/?%1 [L,QSA]
```

`RewriteRule` is matching URI only, you can't attempt matching query string there.
But you can match it within `RewriteCond` condition...

That being said, if you don't care about query string content, but want all the urls that pointed to `newslong.php` redirected to a new location, then it's much simpler:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=[0-9]+$
RewriteRule ^dsk/newslong\.php$ /dsk/ [L,R]
```

If You omit the `R`, then the browser won't be redirected (the user will keep seeing old url) and instead the content will be served via sub-request.

Comment: @anubhava depends... if he only wants to rewrite articles with the `?id=num` in query string than thats an overkill...

Comment: I'll add a note about rewriting the whole uri into new one though

Comment: Sorry to edit your answer, but I thought it was easier to explain than writing code in comments.